# What is the best python regular expression to exclude only a single instance of a comma between a pair of curly brackets?

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

If the line contains more than one comma, I want it returned.

For example, in the following lines I want to return all the lines except `{,}`.

```
{,,,}
{abskdjf}
{,}
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just match on that exactly? For example in Python if the text was a variable called text then `re.sub(r"{,}", "", text)`